# Переменная для инкремента в проекте

Tags: c#

Всем привет.
Мне нужно создать номер для бланка.
В номере есть часть, которая является просто автоинкрементируемым числом.
Вопрос.
Как в C# оптимальнее реализовать хранение такого числа?
Начать с 1, и каждый раз вычитывать из БД какие там последнее число и делать инкремент - это ерунда, как по мне.
Была мыслт засунуть в appsetiongs.json. Но пока не разобрался как можно будет там редактировать значение.
Какие еще могут быть варианты для решения этой задачи?

Comment: Если приложение многопользовательское, то нумерацию лучше отдать БД, т.к. если 2 пользователя будут создавать "одновременно" какую то вашу сущность, то вы получите их с одинаковым номером. Можно в БД создать процедурку, которая будет вам возвращать следующий уникальный номер для вашего бланка. Так что, как по мне, получение номера из БД вполне себе правильная история.

Comment: Документы/бланки где будут храниться? Если в БД, то пусть БД и выдаёт номера при вставке. Для этого в них есть специальные средства (последовательности - sequence).

Comment: Можно вообще не пользоваться автоинкрементом и генерировать всегда уникальный идентификатор uuid, но он будет занимать 16 байт в бинарном виде и 32 символа в текстовом. Если хотим запихивать его в БД то лучше выбрать алгоритм генерации на базе текущего времени (v7)  тогда можно выполнять по ним сортировку и получать из него timestamp создания. Для гнерации можно использовать либу uuidnext

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Начать с 1, и каждый раз вычитывать из БД какие там последнее число и делать инкремент - это ерунда" - совсем не ерунда. Делаете в таблице автоинкрементное поле. Записываете туда новые данные, а потом читаете номер, который был присвоен. Но тут есть один нюанс - если удалите какую-то запись, то будет пропуск номера (приемлемо это или нет - зависит от постановки задачи).

В общем, "начать с 1, и каждый раз вычитывать из БД какие там последнее число и делать инкремент" - это самое то. Причём делать это нужно в самый последний момент, когда точно есть уверенность, что бланк окончательный.

Если приложение многопользовательское, то запросы на получение номера ставите в очередь к единому раздатчику номеров, которым может быть и процедура в БД.